# Select mongo documents whose subdoc array has duplicate field?

Tags: python, mongodb

With a schema like this

```
{
    "doc1": {
        "items": [
            {
                "item_id": 1
            },
            {
                "item_id": 2
            },
            {
                "item_id": 3
            },
        ]
    },
    "doc2": {
        "items": [
            {
                "item_id": 1
            },
            {
                "item_id": 2
            },
            {
                "item_id": 1
            },
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to query for documents that contain a duplicate item in their `items` array field. A duplicate means items with the same `item_id` field.

So the result for the example above should return `doc2` only, because it has two items with the same `item_id`

Something like this?

```
qry = {
    "items": {
        "$size": {
            "$ne": {
                "items.unique_count" # obviously this doesn't exist, not sure how to do it
            }
        }
    }
}
result = MyDocument.find(qry)
```

Comment: You could compare the `"$size"` of `"items"` with the `"$size"` of the set of values (with `"$reduce"`, `"$addToSet"`, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

One option similar to @rickhg12hs and your suggestions is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {$size: "$items"},
          {$size: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$items",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {$setUnion: ["$$value", ["$$this.item_id"]]}
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Vtl8gisuL1_)